# ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) Error while obtaining a new communication channel

Tags: keras, deep-learning, databricks, azure-databricks, tf.keras

I came across this error and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong! It would be really helpful if someone could help me out on this. Thanks!

### Create Output Model Directory

```
dbutils.fs.mkdirs('/CIFAR10/models/')
Out[21]: True


from keras.models import load_model
modelpath = '/dbfs/CIFAR10/models/cifar_2000pictures.h5'
model2000.save(modelpath)​
#model = load_model(modelpath)


ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
Error while obtaining a new communication channel
ConnectException error: This is often caused by an OOM error that causes the connection to the Python REPL to be closed. Check your query's memory usage.
Spark tip settings
```

Answer (score 0):

***OOM (Out Of Memory) issue***, Drive crashed out of memory it's not able to establish a new connection with the driver. Please try the below options:

1. Reduce a load of executors by filtering as much data as possible, Use partition columns. if possible, it will largely decrease the movement of data.
2. Incorrect Configuration here is a possibility that the application fails due to a YARN memory overhead issue (if Spark is running on YARN).You can resolve it by setting the partition size:
   **Increase the value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`**.

> **Why is this happening?**

No matter how big the cluster is. If you are working on dealing with larger datasets, through python pandas that run operations on a single machine, not like spark runs on multiple machines. So, you can increase the memory size of the driver node.

**For more information follow this article:**

https://medium.com/disney-streaming/a-step-by-step-guide-for-debugging-memory-leaks-in-spark-applications-e0dd05118958

https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/apache-spark-out-of-memory-issue-b63c7987fff